# I need to develop a clock with jQuery for players from a game

Tags: jquery, html, css

Well, I need to develop a clock for a HTML page, but I don't want to `getHours` and `getMinutes` from user's pc clock and set it for display, I want to get these values and convert them to the time ingame. The thing is, this clock will be used by users from a specific game that has a different time.

Each real time minute means six minutes ingame, so 10 real minutes are 1 hour ingame. This way, 24 hours ingame are 4 hours for us.

Any help here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to post your code.

Comment: Far too broad of a question to be asked in one shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it too, not done any nice things like formatting but easy to understand:

```
​<div id="clock">Clock</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

var hours = 0;
var minutes = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        updateClock()
    }, 1000);
});

function updateClock() {

    minutes +=6;

    if (minutes > 59) {
        minutes -= 60;
        hours++;
    }
    if (hours > 23) {
        hours = 0;
    }
    $("#clock").html(hours + ':' + minutes);
}​
```

A link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6FkNJ/

Change the hour and minute start time as well as the interval time as necessary

Comment: Works but clicks off 6 minutes every second instead of 6 minutes every minute. But the principle is the same. You might want to fix the single digit thing where you have to add a "0" to the right of the colon when the right number is less than 10. I updated the jsFiddle to do this. [http://jsfiddle.net/6FkNJ/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/6FkNJ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting the time in seconds that the game is starting.

```
var startSecs = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
```

Then calculate using that number to form the hours minutes and seconds to display.

```
// Times 6 converts to game seconds
var elapsedGameSecs = ((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) - startSecs) * 6;
// extract hours and minutes
var gameHour = elapsedGameSecs /3600;
var gameMinute = (elapsedGameSecs % 3600) / 60;
// generate a display string
if (gameMinute < 10) gameMinute = "0" + gameMinute;
var time = gameHour + ":" + gameMinute;
```

You can add a constant number of in-game seconds to make the game time start at a certain time. For example, if you want the starting time to be 8:00 then add 8 * 60 * 60 seconds to the elapsedGameTime before extracting and displaying

Notice that this will mess up after the 24:00 in-game time has passed. You also have to adapt this if you want to use 12:00 as midnight and not 24:00.